# CMD - Import string from file TSV

Tags: cmd

## Hello,

#### I have few TSV files and have few questions

Inside files it looks something like this:

```
 _ID    Slot    Type    Mod   Base  Val Req   Str
 0     Chest    Mag      5     5     5   1  "robe"
 1     Chest    Lig      5     5     5   1  "chest"
 2     Chest    Med      5     5     5   1  "chest"
 3     Chest    Hea      5     5     5   1  "plate"
```

1st i count number of lines inside file using

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" Pref.tsv | find /C ":""
for /f %%p in ('!cmd!') do set Prefe=(%%p-1)
```

this one works nice but when i try select randomly one row by using

```
set /a Pref_rand=(%RANDOM%*%%Prefe/32768)
```

it throws "**Missing operand**" (randomly picks number in range of lines)


Next i want to ask that some rows are not dispalyed correctly by

```
for /F "delims=TAB" %s in (Pref.tsv) do @echo %s
```

for example in file it is :

```
12  Boots   Mag 5   5   5   1   "shoes"
```

and cmd shows `12` 
also 1st row shows only

```
_ID   Slot
```

and some rows shows correctly.

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors here, first there is a missing `/a` when you calculate `Prefe` and then the syntax to retrieve its value is `%Prefe%`, not `%%Prefe`.

This code should work:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=findstr /R /N "^^" Pref.tsv | find /C ":""
for /f %%p in ('!cmd!') do set /a Prefe=(%%p-1)

echo %Prefe%

set /a Pref_rand=(%RANDOM%*%Prefe%/32768)

echo %Pref_rand%
```